# Combining small OpenStreetMap way segments with the same names as one single way segment

Tags: openstreetmap, segment

I am working on a student project using Python. I have extracted way segments from openstreetmap.org using https://overpass-turbo.eu/. I realized at times that there are multiple way segments of the same name. But what I want is to have all the connected ways with the same name (IDs and other tags information notwithstanding) grouped together as a single way. Is there anyway to handle this?

See the first way segment by the name Avenue union

```
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.58.3 b33c3320",
  "osm3s": {
    "timestamp_osm_base": "2022-09-04T19:00:12Z",
    "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
  },
  "elements": [

{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 329384214,
  "nodes": [
    2889868395,
    2889868393
  ],
  "tags": {
    "highway": "residential",
    "lanes": "1",
    "lit": "yes",
    "name": "Avenue Union",
    "oneway": "yes",
    "sidewalk": "both",
    "surface": "asphalt"
  }
}

  ]
}
```

```
Here is the second way segment by name Avenue union
{
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.58.3 b33c3320",
  "osm3s": {
    "timestamp_osm_base": "2022-09-04T19:02:10Z",
    "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
  },
  "elements": [

{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 329384212,
  "nodes": [
    32124407,
    4170219664,
    6831524463,
    1329149166,
    1576231862,
    1576241207,
    1302782850,
    2889868395
  ],
  "tags": {
    "highway": "residential",
    "lanes": "1",
    "lit": "yes",
    "name": "Avenue Union",
    "oneway": "yes",
    "sidewalk": "both",
    "surface": "asphalt"
  }
}

  ]
}
```

In other words, I am only particular about the nodes, all the other tags info are irrelevant to me. So how do I combine the nodes of the two segments in order.

Comment: Please do not repost questions. Instead, Edit the original question. [Grouping OSM ways with the same names as one single way](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/439891/grouping-osm-ways-with-the-same-names-as-one-single-way)

Comment: I'm sorry about this. I guess it's because I'm still new to the platform. I'll adjust accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to download data from https://www.geofabrik.de